# iTunes 12 Apple Music search: is there a way to play all songs returned by search?

Tags: itunes, search, apple-music

Using iTunes 12 on Mac.  I search for an artist in Apple Music.  I get results, including the artist page, albums, songs.  I want to explore this artist, so I want to listen to a stream of his or her songs.  I can only seem to play one song at a time, each with a new play click, or tediously create a playlist by adding each individual song to My Music, then creating a playlist.  Is there no way to stream search results in toto?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes 12.3.1, you can play multiple songs from search results by playing one of the songs listed on the initial search results page -- the one divided into "Top Results" "Songs" "Albums" etc. iTunes will continue playing from your search results after the initial song.

However, you cannot play multiple songs automatically from the detailed search results, e.g. if you click on "Songs" to see the all of the matching songs, and play one from there, it will stop playing at the end of the selected song.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: in iTunes 12.4 you will see a blue Filter button above any search results in the songs list (top one) and it reads [Filter Music for "..." (your search)]. Just click it and go play!